# Questions on multidimensional integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
x^2(1 − y)^2 & 0 ≤ x ≤ y ≤ 1 \\
x + y & 0 ≤ y < x ≤ 1
\end{cases}
$$

1. Argue that $f$ is continuous at all points in $[0, 1] × [0, 1]$ that are not
   in the closed set $\left\{ (x, y) ∈ [0, 1]^2 \;\middle|\; x = y \right\}$, which happens to be exactly the graph of the function $k : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ defined by $k(x) = x$.
2. Prove that $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[0, 1] × [0, 1]$.
3. Apply Fubini’s theorem to calculate the integral on $[0, 1] × [0, 1]$.

I am really stuck on this one. Can someone help? I am doing this on my own and I am really lost

Comment: This is very difficult to read. Try reading the help site's readme on math typesetting

Comment: I am really sorry I can't seem to figure out how to use the website properly

Comment: What are the requirements for being Riemann integrable? What is the definition of continuity?

Comment: A function is riemann integrable if it's graph has jordan content zero. I think that's the requirement here. The definition of continuity is just the epsilon delta definition

Answer (score 0):

1. Remember that $f$ is continuous on a set iff it's continuous at each point in that set. The set $[0,1]^2$, the domain of $f$, is broken into three parts: the red triangle $A$ strictly above the diagonal in $[0,1]^2$, the blue triangle $B$ strictly below the diagonal in $[0,1]^2$, and the purple diagonal $\Delta = \{ (x, x) \in [0,1]^2 : x \in [0,1] \}$. The parts of $f$ are continuous at each point (being a composition of continuous functions) of $A$ and $B$, respectively. Hence $f$ is continuous on $A \cup B$ as desired.
2. Since $f$ is continuous almost-everywhere (on $A \cup B$) on $[0,1]^2$, $f$ is Riemann integrable there.
3. Can you set up the integral to calculate?

---

Refer to this picture of the region:

[image]

You have to break the integral up into two pieces:
\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,1]^2} f &= \int_A f + \int_B f \\
&= \int_{x=0}^{x=1} \int_{y(x)=0}^{y(x)=x} x^2(1-y^2) \, dy \, dx + \int_{y=0}^{y=1} \int_{x(y)=0}^{x(y)=y} \left( x + y \right) \, dx \, dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x} x^2(1-y^2) \, dy \, dx + \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} \left( x + y \right) \, dx \, dy
\end{align*}
Do you see how to set up these integrals? Can you evaluate them?

Comment: 1. How exactly do I check for the boundaries? Can you help me with that?
2. Seems easy and follows from number 1, right?
3. I'm not sure how to set it up considering the function is two different pieces

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: I'll fill out the details in my answer later

Comment: Thank you. I'd appreciate that

Comment: I updated. I'm commenting because I wasn't sure if you'd get a notification otherwise